# Bedeutung von "Immerhin X%"

Tags: single-word-request

Was bedeutet immerhin bezogen auf Daten und Statistiken?

Ausgehend von [der im Duden angegebenen Bedeutung](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/immerhin#Bedeutungc)  schließe ich darauf, dass der Autor beeindruckt von der Zahl ist. Liege ich hiermit richtig?

Bsp.

> Angesichts der Verhältnisse der Rentner sollte es nicht "Nicht einmal", sondern **"Immerhin 50%** der Rentner benutzen das Internet täglich."

Comment: “.... heißen.” Nehme ich an?

Comment: Immerhin and nicht einmal refer to what actually happens compared to what should be expected.

Comment: Meiner Ansicht nach bedeutet immerhin hier genau das gleiche wie in anderen Kontexten.

Comment: @RHa Ja! Sie bewerten die Zahl, und als Grundlage dient eine Erwartung.

Comment: @Philipp: Auch ich verstehe '_immerhin_' mit dem Unterton '_einen derart hohen Wert hätten sicherlich die meisten nicht vermutet._'

Comment: Du verlinkst die Duden-Bedeutung 3 von _»immerhin«_, es sollte Bedeutung 1 sein.

Answer (score 6):

The two expressions differ both in *denotation* and *connotation*.

Denotation: "nicht einmal X" means that the actual value is less than X; "immerhin X" means that the value is X or higher (but presumably close to X).

Connotation: "nicht einmal X" implies that X would be a poor standard to achieve. "immerhin X" implies that a value of X would be respectable.

Answer (score 4):

> dass der Autor beeindruckt von der Zahl ist

Ich würde eher sagen, dass der Autor zufrieden mit der Prozentzahl ist.

In diesem Zusammenhang finde ich es einfacher zu verstehen

"Viele Rentner benutzen das Internet noch sehr selten, aber **immerhin 50% der Rentner benutzen das Internet täglich**."

Answer (score 1):

Ich kann aus der Formulierung weder "Beeindruckung" noch "Zufriedenheit" herauslesen. Sie sagt lediglich aus, dass es schlimmer/weniger sein könnte/n. Wenn man eine steigende Tendenz der Internet-Nutzung bei Rentnern annimmt, könnte da ebenso gut stehen:

> Schon (alternativ: beachtliche )50% der Rentner nutzen das Internet täglich.

Die Duden-Formulierung *eine gewisse Anerkennung* heißt auch nur, dass das positiv zu werten ist und lässt m. E. keine Rückschlüsse auf den Gemütszustand des Autors ob dieser Tatsache zu.

Answer (score 1):

Dem [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/immerhin#Bedeutunga) kann ich nur zustimmen, wenn er von einer gewissen Anerkennung spricht. Denn »immerhin«, gefolgt von einem Prozentwert, bedeutet schon so etwas wie:

> gar nicht so schlecht / nicht so schlecht, wie man erwartet hätte / das schafft nicht jeder / das muss man erstmal schaffen, das geht nicht von selbst / diesen Wert zu erreichen, ist gar nicht so einfach

Answer (score 0):

Immerhin bezogen auf Statistiken bedeutet, das der Wert höher ist, als man als Beobachter/Leser vermuten würde. Es kann aber auch eine eher tröstende Bedeutung haben, dass zwar der gewünschte Wert nicht erreicht wird, aber das er immerhin/zumindest xy% beträgt.

"Immerhin" relating to statistics means, that the value shown is higher than you, as reader would assume. You could also understand it as "making the best of a bad bargain", that the desired value wasn't reached, but "at least" value xy.